# How to set downloaded Firefox to default web browser in Debian?

Tags: debian, firefox, defaults, user-default

How do I set a manually downloaded Firefox as my default web browser so that clicking a link in another application will open the link in this Firefox?

I tried these commands, but they didn't seem to work:

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-www-browser x-www-browser /home/user/firefox/firefox 100
update-alternatives --set x-www-browser /home/user/firefox/firefox
```

What do I have to do?

Comment: - If typing `$ x-www-browser` in the terminal opens the **correct** browser but: - `$ xdg-open https://www.example.com` opens the **wrong** browser application, - editing `~/.config/mimeapps.list` as suggested by @Chalist and then **restarting** should do the trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`update-alternatives` changes the application to use to open a web browser, not the application to use to open a web page. The two are not directly related: “I want to browse the web” is different from “I want to browse this web page”, and there are different kinds of content that happen to all open in a web browser.

What you need to change is which application is associated with the [MIME type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME_type) `text/html`, and perhaps others. These are configured through the [`/etc/mailcap`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=mailcap&sektion=5) file.

On Debian, `/etc/mailcap` is automatically generated from the applications you have installed. When multiple applications can open the same type, there is a priority system (similar, but distinct, from the priority system for alternatives). You can override these priorities by adding entries to [`/etc/mailcap.order`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=mailcap&sektion=5). For example, the following line will cause Firefox to be used in preference of any other application for all the types it supports:

```
firefox:*/*
```

After you've changed `/etc/mailcap.order`, run `/usr/sbin/update-mime` as root to update `/etc/mailcap`.

If you want to use a program that doesn't come from a Debian package, edit it directly into `/etc/mailcap`, in the `User Section`.

```
# ----- User Section Begins ----- #
text/html; /home/user/firefox/firefox '%s'; description=HTML Text; test=test -n "$DISPLAY";  nametemplate=%s.html
# -----  User Section Ends  ----- #
```

If you want to set preferences for your own account, define them in `~/.mailcap`: the entries in that file override the ones in `/etc/mailcap`. You have to put full mailcap lines there, such as

```
text/html; /home/user/firefox/firefox '%s'; description=HTML Text; test=test -n "$DISPLAY";  nametemplate=%s.html
```

Comment: i do this but again don't work. for example in x-chat when i click on link nothing happen.

Answer (score 1):

Run both of the commands as **root** (you should have received a "Permission denied" error when trying to do this without root privileges).
Now if you run (or another application runs) `x-www-browser`, `/home/user/firefox/firefox` should be the one that gets used.

You can also use the convenient interactive mode `update-alternatives --config <name>` to set default applications instead of using `--set`.

Comment: i do this with root access but don't work

Comment: @chalist: Do you receive an error message? What is the output of `update-alternatives --display x-www-browser`?

Comment: `x-www-browser - manual mode
  link currently points to /home/user/firefox/firefox
/home/user/firefox/firefox - priority 100
/usr/bin/chromium - priority 40
Current 'best' version is '/home/user/firefox/firefox'.
`

Comment: How do you see that it's not working? Which browser gets chosen when you start `x-www-browser` yourself?

Comment: when i click a link in application look like choqok i will open in firefox(extracted in home)

Answer (score 0):

For Arch base distros, we have to change `~/.config/mimeapps.list` and replace anywhere your default browser does not set.

For example:

```
  [Default Applications]
  x-scheme-handler/http=userapp-Pale Moon.desktop
  x-scheme-handler/https=userapp-Pale Moon.desktop
  x-scheme-handler/ftp=userapp-Pale Moon.desktop
  x-scheme-handler/chrome=userapp-Pale Moon.desktop
  text/html=userapp-Pale Moon.desktop
  ...
  ... (and anywhere Pale Moon.desktop has been setted)
```

changes to:

```
  [Default Applications]
  x-scheme-handler/http=userapp-chromium.desktop
  x-scheme-handler/https=userapp-chromium.desktop
  x-scheme-handler/ftp=userapp-chromium.desktop
  x-scheme-handler/chrome=userapp-chromium.desktop
  text/html=userapp-chromium.desktop
  ...
```