# How to make xdg-open follow mailcap settings in Debian

Tags: debian, mime-types, defaults, xdg-open

## tl;dr:

In Debian `xdg-open` (through `xdg-mime`) does not follow the `mailcap` specifications used by `run-mailcap` which I prefer to use. **Is there some systematic way to make `xdg-open` follow the `mailcap` entries?** Ideally less hacky than to modify the `xdg-open` script to always call `run-mailcap`.

## Context

Debian (as of 9.5 stretch) has several systems for setting up default applications, or more specifically, associating file extensions, MIME types and programs (or program actions). They are briefly reviewed [in this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/364978/119345). The two main ones with the greatest granularity (in terms of MIME associations) are

1. The "more modern" XDG standard aimed at desktop environments
2. The older `mailcap` system aimed more at mail agents and terminal environments (or desktop agnostic). It is described quite well [in this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46771/119345).

### The goal

I prefer to use the second mailcap system, because its wildcard `mailcap.order` approach makes it very convenient to automatically associate an application with all (or a subset of) the MIME types it supports and can also differentiate between viewers and editors for a given MIME type. This system is also well tied into system updates, i.e. updating packages does not change the association order.

### Execution entry points

Two two methods mentioned above have different entry points

1. XDG uses `xdg-open`
2. the mailcap system uses `run-mailcap` or its aliases (`view`, `edit`)

However, different programs call different entry points, so the results may not be consistent. I'm trying to achieve that though.

### `xdg-open` may fallback on `run-mailcap`

Upon inspection of `/usr/bin/xdg-open` provided by `xdg-utils-1.1.1-1+deb9u1` it seems that `xdg-open` will try to use `xdg-mime` if a desktop is active (in a very generic sense, not necessarily a desktop environment), otherwise it may fallback on `run-mailcap` if it is available.

```
# ... line 787 in /usr/bin/xdg-open
open_generic()
{
    if is_file_url_or_path "$1"; then
        local file="$(file_url_to_path "$1")"

        check_input_file "$file"

        if [ -n "$DISPLAY" ]; then
            filetype=`xdg-mime query filetype "$file" | sed "s/;.*//"`
            open_generic_xdg_mime "$file" "$filetype"
        fi

        if which run-mailcap 2>/dev/null 1>&2; then
            run-mailcap --action=view "$file"
            if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                exit_success
            fi
        fi
# ...
```

## Specific example of inconsistency

The goal is to have Evince as the default viewer for PDF, Djvu, etc.

I have `evince:*/*` in `/etc/mailcap.order` so after running (possibly automatically after updating packages) `update-mime` entries such `application/pdf; evince %s; test=test -n "$DISPLAY"` will come first in `/etc/mailcap`. So launchers using `run-mailcap` use Evince as I want.

However, when something uses `xdg-open`, it will open PDF in Libreoffice Draw. The reason for this is (determined by inserting `set -x` in the script):

1. `xdg-open` calls `xdg-mime query filetype file.pdf` to determine that its MIME type is `application/pdf`
2. it then queries `xdg-mime` whether there is some default application for this MIME type.
3. As I have no actual association, it starts looking for `*.dekstop` entries supporting that MIME type. For each `*.desktop` file it looks at the `InitialPreference` field to determine a good candidate.
4. as `libreoffice-draw.desktop` happens to have `initialPreference=5` it uses it.

Here is the detailed log of the `xdg-mime query default call` with debugging information:

```
$ XDG_UTILS_DEBUG_LEVEL=3 xdg-mime query default application/pdf              
Checking /home/$USER/.config/mimeapps.list
Checking /etc/xdg/mimeapps.list
Checking /home/$USER/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
Checking /usr/share//applications/mimeapps.list
Checking /home/$USER/.local/share/applications/defaults.list and 
        /home/$USER/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
Checking /home/$USER/.local/share/applications/defaults.list and 
         /home/$USER/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
Checking /usr/local/share//applications/defaults.list and 
         /usr/local/share//applications/mimeinfo.cache
Checking /usr/local/share//applications/defaults.list and 
/usr/local/share//applications/mimeinfo.cache
Checking /usr/share//applications/defaults.list and 
         /usr/share//applications/mimeinfo.cache
Checking /usr/share//applications/defaults.list and 
         /usr/share//applications/mimeinfo.cache
 Checking /home/$USER/.local/share/applications/wine-extension-pdf.desktop
   Select /home/$USER/.local/share/applications/wine-extension-pdf.desktop 
           [ -1 => 0 ]
 Checking /usr/share//applications/FoxitReader.desktop
 Checking /usr/share//applications/evince.desktop
 Checking /usr/share//applications/gimp.desktop
 Checking /usr/share//applications/inkscape.desktop
 Checking /usr/share//applications/libreoffice-draw.desktop
   Select /usr/share//applications/libreoffice-draw.desktop [ 0 => 05 ]
 Checking /usr/share//applications/mcomix.desktop
 Checking /usr/share//applications/mupdf.desktop
 Checking /usr/share//applications/pdf-presenter-console.desktop
 Checking /usr/share//applications/vprerex.desktop
 Checking /usr/share//applications/xpdf.desktop
 Checking /usr/share//applications/zathura-pdf-poppler.desktop
 libreoffice-draw.desktop
```

The numbers in `[ X => ]` are obtained by calls such as `awk -F= /InitialPreference=/ {print($2)} /usr/share//applications/libreoffice-draw.desktop`, I determined this by putting `set -x` into the `xdg-mime` script.

## Proposed workarounds so far

Here are workarounds I thought of so far. **I'm looking for some nicer, ideally more systematic solution.**

- One option is to modify the `xdg-open` script to always fallback to `run-mailcap`. But that is a bit of a hack. Even if I use `dpkg-divert`, it still means I have to maintain it myself.
- Use the XDG system and put somethign like `*/*:xdg-open` in `mailcap`. But might result in circular calling in terminal sessions.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a question or an answer or both?

Comment: A question, looking for nicer workarounds than I found so far. I will try to stress that point, thank you for the comment.

Comment: I guess the best approach is to submit a bug against XDG tools on FDO.

Answer (score 1):

I'm frequently puzzled by various `xdg-open` limitations, too.

I don't pretend to be complete here, but I'm using the following desktop entry:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
NoDisplay=true
Exec=run-mailcap %u
Name=run-mailcap
Comment=run-mailcap
```

and delegate everything to it in my `mimeapps.list`:

```
[Default Applications]
application/ogg=run-mailcap.desktop
application/pdf=run-mailcap.desktop
application/postscript=run-mailcap.desktop
application/rar=run-mailcap.desktop
application/rss+xml=run-mailcap.desktop
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document=run-mailcap.desktop
application/x-cue=run-mailcap.desktop
application/x-extension-eml=run-mailcap.desktop
application/x-extension-htm=run-mailcap.desktop
application/x-extension-html=run-mailcap.desktop
application/x-extension-rss=run-mailcap.desktop
application/x-extension-xhtml=run-mailcap.desktop
application/x-ms-dos-executable=run-mailcap.desktop
application/x-xpinstall=run-mailcap.desktop
application/xhtml+xml=run-mailcap.desktop
application/xml=run-mailcap.desktop
application/xspf+xml=run-mailcap.desktop
application/zip=run-mailcap.desktop
audio/midi=run-mailcap.desktop
audio/prs.sid=run-mailcap.desktop
...
```

Theoretically, it's possible to convert this and/or your custom diversions of `xdg-open` to a virtual `xdg-utils` implementation.